# when i reload my popup window, a copy of window is opened in new tab automatically

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am very new to asp.net and javascript. my page abcd.aspx page had a button named popup. when i click my button, is show popup window(popup.aspx). in popup window there is dropdownlist. when selection of dropdownlist changed, popup.aspx get reloading. my problem is when reloading popup, copy of popup window is opened in new tab automatically. please any one explain me to avoid this. and also when i close my popup window, how to reload my parent page automatically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_popup() {
    var getUserid;
    getUserid = document.getElementById('l_userid').innerText;
    var i = "toolbar:no;dialogheight:540px;dialogwidth:750px;status:no;center:yes;resizable:no";
    window.showModalDialog("popup.aspx?userid=" + getUserid, 'vallaban', i); 
}
<body>
<td><input type="button" value="popup" onclick="open_popup()" /></td>
</body>


----popup.aspx------
<asp:Panel ID="tab2" runat="server" >
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>name :</td>
   <td> 
       <asp:ListBox ID="update_lb_name" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"   OnSelectedIndexChanged="fvt_OnSelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
   </td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Customer Code :</td>
    <td><asp:ListBox ID="update_lb_customer_code" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" />  </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><asp:Button ID="Update_btn" runat="server" Text="update" /> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I imagine your problem is in `popup.aspx` and with that dropdown list, if the page refreshes when clicking the drop-down try adding `e.preventDefault()` to the click event.

Comment: this is fine . one more doubt. how to reload abcd.aspx automatically when popup.aspx is closed @Simon Staton